# DFS trees and DFS forests

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I was learning about DfS trees from:

http://rosalind.info/glossary/algo-depth-first-search/

In the "Depth-first search in directed graphs" section if we add a node **Z** with no edges pointing towards it but only one edge from Z to C, then where would Z appear in the resulting DFS tree?

*Would its edge from Z to C be considered a tree edge or a cross edge?*

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual Problem? Understanding/Applying the terminology or building the new DFS tree?

Comment: @makadev understanding what happens when such a node (as described) is added to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the new DFS tree for the given question it will be obvious:

1. The current DFS tree for exploration of A to H is the same. Z is not part of it since it is not connected by any Edge to Z. Due to lexicographic order in selecting vertices, it won't be selected before A.
2. After visiting A to H, Z is not visited and those will be - in lexicographic order - selected for exploration. It will be a new *Tree* in the DFS forest.
   Be aware that in the unidirectional case, this is only a DFS forest when you ignore the *non-tree edges* as shown in the sample.
3. The Terminology states that Cross Edges *... lead to a node that has already been completely explored*. Z has an Edge to the previously explored C, those it's edge is a Cross Edge.

You should check this answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How the tree (or forest) looks and what type of edge ZC is depends on where the DFS is run from, and what nodes are chosen first. If the DFS visits Z before it visits C, then ZC will be a tree edge as it is the only and Z will be a part of a tree with multiple nodes. If DFS starts at Z, then there will be one tree with Z as the root node. However, if Z is only discovered once C has already been visited, then C must also have been finished (completely explored) because Z cannot be reached by any other nodes. Thus in this case, ZC is a cross edge and Z would be in a tree by itself.